# How to avoid repetitive logging of unique ID using log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

In my application that runs in 10s of thousands of lines of code, I see that people are logging a unique ID (lets say request ID) with every log statement. Given the multithreaded nature and multiple requests coming to the box, I do see why logging this request ID once in the start does not work. As other request may come in between and logs will then be mixed up.

Is there any neater way of doing this with log4j2.

Comment: How you generating unique `ID`?

Comment: Caller passes it to the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem and in Log4j2 you can use the [ThreadContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) map to solve it.

When a request enters your code, set a unique ID in the ThreadContext:

```
ThreadContext.put("id", uniqueID());
```

From here on, all logging that happens in the same thread will have a map with "id" as key and the value you specified. You can use this for [filtering](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#ThreadContextMapFilter), [routing](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files), and you can make the map appear in the log file with the `%X` conversation pattern. If you only want a specific key (e.g., "id"), use `%X{id}` in your [pattern layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout).

When you're done, remove the key with `ThreadContext.remove("id")`.

Recently Log4j2 added [CloseableThreadContext](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html#CloseableThreadContext) which automatically removes key-value pairs when you're done with them.

Comment: Hi Remko. This is not the right place for this request, but can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746157/log4j2-setting-printobject-to-true-in-custom-appender .. when you get a chance.

Comment: Ok but super busy. Give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Mapped Dignostic Context ([MDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html)). It is basically ThreadLocal that gets appended to all messages logged by same thread. You have to include it in the pattern. Also do not forget to clear the MDC.

In web applications it is usually done by Filter.

Comment: For Log4J 2 look [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html).