# log4j2 overriding close method in custom appenders

Tags: logging, log4j2

In log4j-1, we required override close() method.

> @Override  public void close(){  .....     }

But that does not seem to be the case in log4j2.

Any thoughts on why this is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j2's Appender interface extends Lifecycle which has a `stop()` method that is called when the logging subsystem shuts down. This is where you would release any resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Kindly have a look at this one as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746157/log4j2-setting-printobject-to-true-in-custom-appender